# How to add warping function to code in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, sudoku

I am currently working on creating program that detects sudoku puzzle from image and solves it. However I am stuck on warping image part, no idea how to do it. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a function to detect the sudoku puzzle
def detect_sudoku_puzzle(image):
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

    # Find contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the contour with maximum area
    contour_with_max_area = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Find the bounding box of the contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour_with_max_area)

    # Crop the image
    cropped_image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # Return the cropped image
    return cropped_image

image = cv2.imread('sudoku.jpg')
cropped_image = detect_sudoku_puzzle(image)

plt.imshow(cropped_image)
plt.show()

cv2.imshow('aaaaa', cropped_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried to use cv2.warpPerspective function but it requires transformation matrix and I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: Well, that's the trick, right?  You have to use those contours to figure out the actual shape that you scanned.  If you can get the coordinates of the four corners, then unwarping is pretty easy.

Comment: Can you give me a tip how to get  those coordinates?

Comment: Have you looked at the contour list to see how it relates to the image?

Comment: Did you try to use `getPerspectiveTransform` function? See [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html). If you need more help please share share an example input image and a sketch what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed an app in Android (Java) to scan a sudoku grid. For a slightly warped image it works well. Most of the time the image is warped at the corners and you can't determine the coordinates of the cells located in these warped corners. The central part of the grid is much less warped, so you can extrapolate and interpolate from the coordinates of the 4 corners/crosses of the central block to determine the coordinates of the 81 cells. From that on you could affine-transform the image of each cell. I didn't implement that transformation in my app because: 1) it's time consuming, and 2) once we've got the coordinates of the cells, the text recognition API (ML-Kit) I'm using is very efficient for recognizing digits in the cells even in the warped ones (we don't need to recognize other characters). Sometimes one misses some coordinates, but it's not dramatic, one simply re-scan the grid!

Watch this instructive video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOC-ad0BsY0.